# как считать url вместе с параметрами get или отдельно параметры как ссылку ? Laravel

Tags: javascript, html5, laravel

мне нужно чтобы в пагинатор подставилось 
ссылка как http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_course?courses=0&country=0&city=los_angeles?page=1

сейчас при такой ссылка получается только

```html
<a href="{{url()->current() .'?page='. $i}}" ></a>
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_course?page=1

Спасибо!

Comment: `url()->full()` вернет ссылку со всеми параметрами, а кнопки страниц лучше генерировать как `$collection->appends(request()->all())->links()`

Comment: спасибо, то  что нужно напишите ответ = выберу вопрос